# Corrupted Images From BitmapFactory

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory, corrupt-data

Once in a while when I am downloading images, some of them will appear with gray lines as displayed in the sample image below:
[image: Example]

This tends to happen exclusively on poor network conditions.

My code for decoding images is essentially a modded version of that from UIL:

```
Bitmap decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, decodingOptions);
```

where stream is just an InputStream to the remote file

Now I've seen this behaviour on the Google Play Music app which makes me wonder if it's an issue with the BitmapFactory. 
The only solution I've come up with so far is maybe doing a checksum comparison to make sure the entire image was downloaded.

Edit:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = getConnection(path);
InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream()
stream = new ContentLengthInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(download, BUFFER_SIZE), conn.getContentLength())
```

Comment: I don't think its related to BitmapFactory as its only decoding the stream, it would be more like the steam not being filled completely, and yes, doing a MD5 checksum would suffice and then you can just read the file and get the Uri for it.

Comment: @Raykud The only reason I'm hesitant to the checksum solution is that it adds overhead to every single image download. I've posted the code I use to get the InputStream if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using the following steps:

- Open an InputStream to the image as normal
- Write the stream to a ByteArrayOutputStream
- Compare the length of the ByteArrayOutputStream to the Content-Length header from the HttpURLConnection
- If mismatch then you've lost data in transit
- Otherwise you can convert your ByteArrayOutputStream to a ByteArrayInputStream and use with the BitmapFactory as you see fit